# Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'TableViewCell' from 'UITableViewCell'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying this code and getting below warning

> Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'GuideTableViewCell' from 'UITableViewCell'

in line

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"BusinessTableViewCell"];
```

Full Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   BusinessTableViewCell * cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BusinessTableViewCell"];
   if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"BusinessTableViewCell"];
   }

   BusinessInfo * business = self.businesses[indexPath.row];
   cell.business = business;
   return cell;
}
```

Also tried

```
BusinessTableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"BusinessTableViewCell"];
```

still getting the error can any one kindly give me some help.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in your code. It should be:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    BusinessTableViewCell * cell = (BusinessTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BusinessTableViewCell"];

    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[BusinessTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"BusinessTableViewCell"];
    }

    BusinessInfo * business = self.businesses[indexPath.row];
    cell.business = business;

    return cell;
}
```

1. You need to cast `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to the proper class.
2. When you create a new cell, it needs to be of the proper type.

Comment: Why is the self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier required. the code works without that. it just gives a warning.

Comment: It facilitates cell reuse making the table view far more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, yes little bit of performance improvements in each bit of code goes all the way to great improvement in the total app performance.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because your code cannot possibly work.

Your code expects a BusinessTableViewCell. You create a UITableViewCell. You should be creating a BusinessTableViewCell.

Comment: Code Works But just gives a warning !